# MySQL performance in this case?

Tags: mysql

Generally, is it better to have 10 threads with different connections doing 1 update each, or have one single connection doing 10 updates, in one thread, one after another?

In all cases a `COMMIT` will happen in the end.

Comment: In the single thread version, is there a COMMIT at the end of all 10, or is there a COMMIT after each update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have one thread doing 10 updates then a single commit at the end.

The reasons are:

- there is considerable effort for the database to start and commit a transaction. If you do it all in one transaction to incur this cost just once
- the communications involved in executing a query is quite "chatty" - most of the comms involves getting ready to run and tidying up. The comms around the update query itself would be quite small. If you have only 1 communication session you save a lot of comms overhead
- most of the effort of executing a query is in the secondary issues of security, permissions, syntax checking, etc - *not* doing the actual data manipulation. Using one session will save at least some of the duplicated effort that multiple sessions would incur

However, the best thing would be to simply test the two options in as realistic a way as you can.

Answer (score 1):

is it better to have 10 threads with different connections doing 1 update each if
threads dont need to be seriality and each update relate with separate tables

Comment: true if only number of CPU cores more than 10